# Google forms onFormSubmit (whilst editing) causes duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api, google-forms

**Edit:**

Here is an execution transcript, of editing an existing contact form (*i see nothing about deleting any existing contact??*).

```
[14-01-21 13:39:03:306 EST] Starting execution
[14-01-21 13:39:03:311 EST] FormResponse.getItemResponses() [0.001 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:03:311 EST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:03:312 EST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:03:312 EST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:03:312 EST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:03:312 EST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:03:312 EST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:03:312 EST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:03:312 EST] (class).getResponse() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:03:456 EST] ContactsApp.getContactGroup([System Group: My Contacts]) [0.143 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:04:634 EST] ContactGroup.getContacts() [1.178 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:04:637 EST] Contact.getEmails([WORK_EMAIL]) [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:04:637 EST] EmailField.toString() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:04:718 EST] ContactsApp.createContact([JOTTER, BOT, jotterbot@stackoverflow.com]) [0.08 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:04:719 EST] Contact.getEmails([HOME_EMAIL]) [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:04:802 EST] EmailField.setLabel([WORK_EMAIL]) [0.082 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:04:877 EST] EmailField.setAsPrimary() [0.074 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:04:959 EST] Contact.addPhone([MOBILE_PHONE, 12345]) [0.081 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:168 EST] Contact.addPhone([WORK_PHONE, 67890]) [0.209 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:252 EST] Contact.addCompany([CompanyInc, BadCoderYep]) [0.083 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:386 EST] Contact.addAddress([WORK_ADDRESS, 123 Company Place, Suburb, State]) [0.133 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:625 EST] Contact.addToGroup([ContactGroup]) [0.237 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:625 EST] Contact.toString() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:625 EST] ContactGroup.addContact([Contact]) [0.237 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:625 EST] Contact.getEmails([WORK_EMAIL]) [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:625 EST] EmailField.toString() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:696 EST] ContactsApp.createContact([JOTTER, BOT, jotterbot@stackoverflow.com]) [0.069 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:696 EST] Contact.getEmails([HOME_EMAIL]) [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:766 EST] EmailField.setLabel([WORK_EMAIL]) [0.069 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:823 EST] EmailField.setAsPrimary() [0.056 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:05:986 EST] Contact.addPhone([MOBILE_PHONE, 12345]) [0.162 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:06:062 EST] Contact.addPhone([WORK_PHONE, 67890]) [0.075 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:06:145 EST] Contact.addCompany([CompanyInc, BadCoderYep]) [0.082 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:06:236 EST] Contact.addAddress([WORK_ADDRESS, 123 Company Place, Suburb, State]) [0.091 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:06:389 EST] Contact.addToGroup([ContactGroup]) [0.152 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:06:389 EST] Contact.toString() [0 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:06:389 EST] ContactGroup.addContact([Contact]) [0.152 seconds]
[14-01-21 13:39:06:390 EST] Execution succeeded [3.079 seconds total runtime]
```

*Is this a recursion problem or something?*

I have a form that adds a contact directly into my Gmail contacts - taking values from the form.

On first submit it works fine, but when I edit the form again, I get 2 x the new contact with edited details and the old contact remains. When ran again 4 x contacts are added, then 8 x contact, and so on.

Seems like a silly mistake. What am I missing here?

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {

var formResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();

  var firstName = formResponses[0].getResponse().toString();
  var lastName = formResponses[1].getResponse().toString();
  var emailAddress = formResponses[2].getResponse().toString();
  var company = formResponses[3].getResponse().toString();
  var position = formResponses[4].getResponse().toString();
  var mobileNumber = formResponses[5].getResponse().toString();
  var workNumber = formResponses[6].getResponse().toString();
  var workAddress = formResponses[7].getResponse().toString();

  // Get all of our contacts in group "My Contacts". 
  // Later we will check the submitted values against the existing contacts to avoid duplicates.
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
  var myContacts = group.getContacts();

  // try finding contact first by email address to avoid duplicates.
  for (var i = 0; i < myContacts.length; i++) {

    if(myContacts[i].getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL)[0] == emailAddress) { 

      //contact exists so lets update it's values to latest in form submission
      //var contact = ContactsApp.getContact(emailAddress).deleteContact();

      myContacts[i].deleteContact();

      var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, emailAddress);
        contact.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL)[0].setLabel(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL);
        contact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, mobileNumber);
        contact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE, workNumber);
        contact.addCompany(company, position);
        contact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS, workAddress);

      group.addContact(contact);

    } else {

      //contact does not yet exist so we will create it from scratch  
      var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, emailAddress);
        contact.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL)[0].setLabel(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL);
        contact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, mobileNumber);
        contact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE, workNumber);
        contact.addCompany(company, position);
        contact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS, workAddress);

        // Adding our contact to the "My Contacts" group
        group.addContact(contact);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think inside the if loop, you should delete the current contact that matched the condition.  myContacts[i].deleteContact();

Comment: Thanks Amit for responding! I have made the change but it still causes duplicates. I will update the page to reflect my current code.

Answer (score 0):

In the interests of internet justice, here is the solution.

I did a few things wrong, but after asking [on the google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/9b2yV7UUm64/MTNh-FNfFsIJ), I was told I was comparing an emailAddress object to a string value, therefore my check would always fail and a new contact would be created regardless.  At any rate, the method for which I determine an existing contact has changed in the final code.

And so here is the refined code working in the Form (trigger is set for onFormSubmit):

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var formResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();

  var firstName = formResponses[0].getResponse().toString();
  var lastName = formResponses[1].getResponse().toString();
  var emailAddress = formResponses[2].getResponse().toString();
  var company = formResponses[3].getResponse().toString();
  var position = formResponses[4].getResponse().toString();
  var mobileNumber = formResponses[5].getResponse().toString();
  var workNumber = formResponses[6].getResponse().toString();
  var workAddress = formResponses[7].getResponse().toString();

  // Get all of our contacts in group "My Contacts". 
  var myContactsGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts"); 

  // Check to see if the email address already exists
  var existingContact = ContactsApp.getContact(emailAddress);  

  // If the email address doesn't exist, create a new contact and add it to the group
  if (existingContact == null)
  {
    var newContact = ContactsApp.createContact(firstName, lastName, emailAddress);
    newContact.getEmails(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_EMAIL)[0].setLabel(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_EMAIL).setAsPrimary();
    newContact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, mobileNumber);
    newContact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE, workNumber);
    newContact.addCompany(company, position);
    newContact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS, workAddress);

    myContactsGroup.addContact(newContact);
  }

  // Otherwise simply update the details of the existing contact
  else
  { 
    existingContact.setGivenName(firstName);
    existingContact.setFamilyName(lastName);
    existingContact.setFullName(firstName + " " + lastName);
    existingContact.getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE)[0].setPhoneNumber(mobileNumber);
    existingContact.getPhones(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_PHONE)[0].setPhoneNumber(workNumber);
    existingContact.getCompanies()[0].setCompanyName(company);
    existingContact.getCompanies()[0].setJobTitle(position);
    existingContact.getAddresses(ContactsApp.Field.WORK_ADDRESS)[0].setAddress(workAddress);    
  }
}
```